# Meaning of "or 1 in p" in Wikipedia article on Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, distributions

I was taking a closer look at this table in the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_deviation_and_coverage.

[image]

It is the 4th column labeled `or 1 in p` that I'm having trouble with. It seems to be the inverse of the 3rd column, `1-p`. What is the meaning of `or 1 in p`?

Comment: This is the value of $1/(1-p)$, there is one chance out of $3.1514$, $21.978$, &tc. to fall outside the interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed the inverse of $1-p$. The column is mislabelled, since $p$ is already defined.

They are writing $1-p$ as a fraction $1/M$, and telling you $M$. It can get hard to compare very small fractions intuitively, but writing them as $1$ in $M$ can be more intuitive (e.g. "how many times would we need to repeat this sampling from a normal, to expect to see one value at least this many SDs from the mean?". Framed this way, it's effectively a "[return period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_period#Return_period_as_the_reciprocal_of_expected_frequency)", which is a common way to express rare events like floods or extreme storms.)